# Angular ui-bootstrap popover is not changing scope model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Please, someone there some idea why angular `ui-bootstrap popover` is not changing the model in scope?

```
<button popover-placement="right" 
        uib-popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'"
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default">Click me!</button>

....

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date:</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            ng-model="dataClonada" 
            datepicker-options="dateOptionsClone" 
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{formats[5]}}" 
            is-open="popup3"
            readonly="true"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="popup3=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="show()">show value</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

I did one simple plunker to show the situation.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ebYWI8hP0xtOboY2v37Z?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
ng-model="dataClonada"
```

to

```
ng-model="$parent.variable"
```

The directive (apparently) is creating a new child scope, so you need to use [`$parent`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent) to access the parent scope and access it's values (where `variable` resides).

[Fixed plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LW9fxK4YjxGTQR9P8oHc?p=preview)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaanks

Answer (score 1):

For some reason for me it worked with double parent:

```
ng-model="$parent.$parent.variable"
```

Can be, because the popover was inside of a repeater?